# Jasmine.js v2.0.0 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am new to Jasmine2 JS framework. I am using Jasmine.js framework to create test suites for my application developed in Backbone.js framework.

When I am creating test cases for Backbone.js -> views home.js file, one of my home.js views function has

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

and another function has

```
event.preventDefault();
```

If my Backbone.js -> views function has **event.stopPropagation(); and event.preventDefault();**, my test suites throws error as below:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined**

How to write a test cases for my views function which has `event.stopPropagation(); and event.preventDefault();`

or

how to skip these has event.stopPropagation(); and event.preventDefault(); when I am calling function from Jasmine.js framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code, I hope this works for you to test events:

```
            var event = {
                type: 'click',
                stopPropagation: function () {},
                preventDefault: function () {}
            };          
            var stopPropagationSpy  = spyOn(event, 'stopPropagation');
            var preventDefaultSpy   = spyOn(event, 'preventDefault');           
            {OBJ}.{FUNCTION_TO_CALL}(event);
            $("{YOUR_ELEMENT_TO_TRIGGER}").trigger(event);
            expect(stopPropagationSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
            expect(preventDefaultSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
```

Answer (score -1):

This error means that **event** is undefined, not stopPropogation().

```
submitClicked(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault(); <-- e would be undefined.
}
```